# Multiple IntentService instances working with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, intentservice

I have an IntentService that does the following:
 - (possibly) adds an entry to a SQLite database
 - goes through the entries in the database to see if an action should be taken, and if so, updates/removes the entry

A new IntentService may be created while one already is running, meaning they will have to battle for database access. Due to my non-existant experience with threading, and very limited experience with databases in general, I am not sure how to best handle this.

My plan goes something like this:
 (- if adding an entry, lock database, add entry, unlock database)

- lock database
- return first entry to be processed, if any
- update the entry so that subsequent database scans will not return the entry as an entry that should be processed
- unlock database
- process entry
- if entry processed successfully, lock database, remove entry from database, unlock database
- repeat until no more entries to be processed

This makes sense to me, on paper... Multiple instances of the IntentService should be able to work side by side. Although I would prefer that just one IntentService would do its thing at a time since they will be performing network operations as well. Is it a good approach? Are there better ways of doing it?